# Displaying the 'like' button in a Javascript pop-up

Tags: facebook, popup, facebook-like

My web site uses iBox (http://www.enthropia.com/labs/ibox/) to display information that I would like users to be able to share using the `'Like'` and `'Send'` buttons.

I have included the proper javascript and html for the 'like' button on both the parent page and the pop-up page, but the 'like' button itself (the xfbml in the pop-up page) does not appear at all.

I have tried different combinations of including the javascript and the fb-root div in both the parent and pop-up pages, but nothing seems to be working.  Has anyone done this?  Is there something else I should try?  Viewing the pop-up page directly does reveal the 'like' button, but it does not show up in the pop-up.

Code from the pop-up HTML:

```
<span id="fblikebutton">
    <fb:like action="recommend" show_faces="true" width="450" send="true" href="http://..."></fb:like>
</span>
<script type="text/javascript">
    FB.XFBML.parse(document.getElementById('fblikebutton'));
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are adding popup dynamically, you might need FB.XFBML.parse() call after you add the XFBML like button.

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.XFBML.parse/

Comment: Hmm, I added that call to the popin HTML surrounded by <script> tags after the 'like' button (and even tried putting the button in a span and referring to its ID), and it seems to execute, but still no button.  Any other ideas?  Thanks so much for your fast help; I had definitely not seen that before.

Comment: Sure.  In the root page, I have links like this:
`<a href="http://********.com/popin/special.php?..." rel="ibox&height=450" class="l1 info">`

In the HTML for the pop-up, the facebook like code is as follows:
`<span id="fblikebutton">
<fb:like action="recommend" show_faces="true" width="450" send="true" href="http://..."></fb:like>
</span>
<script type="text/javascript">
FB.XFBML.parse(document.getElementById('fblikebutton'));
</script>`
Everything else seems to check out.  I put the javascript function code and fb-root div in the parent page.

Comment: Actually, I put that command as an action for a button and it worked--I think the command just wasn't being executed.  Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: @SemunLee : You sir saved my day, I had the same problem of a FB-Like button "magically" showing (or not) when displayed in a light-box.
The button's context must be displayed before the button itself is built by fb api.
Now with that neat little function call strategically placed you solved my problem.
A question yet remains ... Why does this button need to be rendered in an "already displayed" context to get it's proper size ?